# C# equivalent to hash_hmac in PHP

Tags: c#, hmac, sha512

using .NET and C# i need to provide an integrity string using HMAC SHA512 to a PHP server .
Using in C#  :

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
HMACSHA512 hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(keyByte);
byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
byte[]  hashmessage = hmacsha512.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
return(ByteToString(hashmessage).toUpper());
```

But it doesn't match with PHP hash_hmac()
PHP code :

```
$hmac = strtoupper(hash_hmac($pbx_hash, $msg, $binKey));
```

I try to change encoding in C# (utf8, ASCII,Unicode) Without success.

I've tried many solution found on the net but nothing give the same string :(

I can't change the PHP code,  and doesn't see what's wrong in C#

**Edit** This is `ByteToString` (copied from the comment):

```
static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
{
    string sbinary = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
    {
        sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); /* hex format */
    }
    return (sbinary);
}
```

After many tets, in found that i get the same results if PHP hash_hmac key is a string, not a byte Array . Seems that the problem is with the PHP convert function $binKey = pack("H*", $keyTest);

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hmac+c%23

Comment: chech this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx

Comment: What is` ByteToString` ?

Answer (score 44):

The problem must be the actual representation of the key/message data.

See the following tests:

### `PHP`

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
print strtoupper(hash_hmac("sha256", "message", "key"));
?>
```

Output (live via http://writecodeonline.com/php/):

```
6E9EF29B75FFFC5B7ABAE527D58FDADB2FE42E7219011976917343065F58ED4A
```

### `C#`

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    private const string key = "key";
    private const string message = "message";
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            hmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(message));

            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", ByteToString(hmacsha256.Hash));
        }
    }
    static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
    {
        string sbinary = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
            sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); /* hex format */
        return sbinary;
    }    
}
```

Output (live via http://ideone.com/JdpeL):

```
Result: 6E9EF29B75FFFC5B7ABAE527D58FDADB2FE42E7219011976917343065F58ED4A
```

So, check the character set/encoding of the PHP input data. Also check the actual algorithm (in `$pbx_hash`).

Comment: Thank you, here's the code for ByteToString : static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
{
string sbinary = "";
for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
{
sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); // hex format
}
return (sbinary);
} I supposeit will give the same return.

Comment: sehe, There are already built-in classes for this `BitConverter.ToString` , `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary`

Comment: Thank you, Bitconverter is shorter but it doesn't solve te problem of the difference between PHP and C# :(

Comment: @Philippe I have redone my analysis given your `ByteToString` function. See my answer rewritten from scratch

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, after many tests the problems comes from PHP Pack(H*  function ! when the key provided is a string it's ok but using Pack(H* to provide key give different result from C# GetBytes (probably because of internal PHP encoding). Found the solution here : http://www.nuronconsulting.com/c-pack-h.aspx

Comment: Sooo, indeed, I was right. The error was in the key or message input.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use encoding.GetString(hmacsha256.Hash) ?

Answer (score 20):

```
    private static string HashHmac(string message, string secret)
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        using (HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(encoding.GetBytes(secret)))
        {
            var msg = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(msg);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i was working in c# from a PHP 'hash_hmac()' example, and was able to get desired results using above answer.

Comment: Many APIs want a base64 version of the hash, you can simply get this by replacing the existing 'return...' line with return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

Comment: Could you please explain why you need the .Replace("-", string.Empty)  ?

Answer (score 4):

As said upper, the problem was with PHP Pack(H* function used to convert key to byte array.
C# Getbytes doesn't give the same result (utf8, asci, unicode...).
The solution found here : http://www.nuronconsulting.com/c-pack-h.aspx was ok for me.
now HMAC from C# match with PHP !

```
public static byte[] PackH(string hex)
{
       if ((hex.Length % 2) == 1) hex += '0';
       byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
       for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
       {
             bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
       }
 return bytes;
}
```

Manu thanks to all for your help.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I've tried using your approach but still having issues. I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276909/string-with-convert-tochar0-hash-result-different-than-chr0-in-php-when-hash . Can you give me info WHERE in your solution you actually used this PackH function? thanks!