# api authentication (c# to php)

Tags: c#, php, api, authentication

I need help.

I'm trying connect a website by API, but it requests authentication.
They show me example by **C#** but I want to change into **PHP**.

I use `file_get_content`s for getting data. 
How I have to send them in the **HTML** Header of my request with their name.
How I make signature.

There is explaining of website.
in sum can you convert C# to PHP please :)

---

**API Authentication:**

All API calls related to a user account require authentication.

You need to provide **3** parameters to authenticate a request:

```
"X-PCK": API key
"X-Stamp": Nonce
"X-Signature": Signature
API key
```

You can create the API key from the Account > API Access page in your exchange account.

**Nonce:**

Nonce is a regular integer number. It must be increasing with every request you make.

A common practice is to use unix time for that parameter.

**Signature:**

Signature is a `HMAC-SHA256` encoded message. The `HMAC-SHA256` code must be generated using a private key that contains a timestamp and your API key

**Example (C#):**

```
string message = yourAPIKey + unixTimeStamp;
using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String( yourPrivateKey ))){

   byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

   string X-Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes));
}
```

After creating the parameters, you have to send them in the HTML Header of your request with their name

**Example (C#):**

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-PCK", yourAPIKey);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Stamp", stamp.ToString());
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Signature", signature);
```

Comment: What php do you have so far?

Comment: I have just started. i'm novice

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) instead of file_get_contents.

Exemple :

```
// API Url
$url = 'http://';
// Put the value of parameters
$yourAPIKey = "";
$stamp = "";
$signature = "";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('X-PCK: '. $yourAPIKey, 'X-Stamp: '. $stamp, 'X-Signature: '. $signature),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => 1
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// echo response output
echo $response;
```

Comment: but how I use curl, can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Use curl. Take an example like this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-init.php

For the headers use something like that

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    '"X-PCK": API key',
    '"X-Stamp": Nonce',
    '"X-Signature": Signature'
));
```

Comment: how I create signature

Comment: Search through the PHP Manual and Google: For HMACSHA256 in C# you will need http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash-hmac.php. For Convert.FromBase64String is http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-decode.php. Equal to ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(message)); in php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804231/c-sharp-equivalent-to-hash-hmac-in-php. Convert.ToBase64String is http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php