# php hash_hmac to c# - webresponse "NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED"

Tags: c#, php

I try to convert a php-code to c#

php

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecretkey='yyy';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://website.com/api/getsomething?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecretkey);
$resource = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($resource);
$obj = ($execResult);
```

and here my C#

```
WebRequest _WebRequest;
WebResponse _WebResponse;
string apikey = "xxx";
string apisecret = "yyy";
string nonce = ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
string uri = $"https://website.com/api/getsomething?apikey={apikey}nonce={nonce}";
string _Hash_hmac = Hash_hmac(uri, apisecret);

_WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
_WebRequest.Headers["apisign"] = _Hash_hmac;

_WebResponse = _WebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The Code for Hash-hmac I use this [C# equivalent to hash_hmac in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804231/c-sharp-equivalent-to-hash-hmac-in-php)

The Webresponse is always *"NONCE_NOT_PROVIDED"*

I checked the outcome from the hash_hmac with the one in php - they are the same.
And also try string ToUpper and ToLower.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: replace the line **string uri = $"https://website.com/api/getsomething?apikey={apikey}nonce={nonce}";** with this line **string uri = $"https://website.com/api/getsomething?apikey={apikey}&nonce={nonce}";**

Comment: I Thought the '&' it was a part of the PHP syntax. Now it looks better. Just get "INVALID_SIGNATURE"

Comment: This might be due to the parameters you are passing. You should debug the code ( both **php** & **c#** ) because the date-value you're passing in c# is in different format.

Comment: Problem solved.

Had to change the HMACSHA256 to HMACSHA512 to calculate the hash. It is not written in the documentation of the API

Thanks for the help

Comment: Good luck @GustavoBesade

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an ampersand (&)?

```
apikey={apikey}nonce={nonce}
```

becomes

```
apikey={apikey}&nonce={nonce}
```

I would advise reading your code more closely with these kinds of errors.